# The "CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build my app, but following error pops up. A couple of days ago, I had no problems with building it.

```
Error       The "CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\VectorCompat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar'.
File name: 'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\VectorCompat\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar'
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.SizeAndContentFileComparer.GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
at System.Linq.Set`1.InternalGetHashCode(TElement value)
at System.Linq.Set`1.Find(TElement value, Boolean add)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__63`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.DistinctFilesByContent(IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    TotemAndroid
```

Should I delete the VectorCompat component and add it again? Why is it suddenly giving this error when it built fine a couple of days ago?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like you have duplicate library

Comment: check for duplicate libraries and remove it, unfortunately i dont know xamarin so can't help you beyond this

Answer (score 3):

It appears some artefacts aren't being copied to your `obj` folder, namely `VectorCompat`'s `classes.jar`. I would suggest deleting your `obj` folder manually and rebuilding the solution.